# $n^2 + (n+1)^2 = m^3$ has no solution in the positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem from Burton: show that the equation $n^2 + (n+1)^2 = m^3$ has no solution in the positive integers.

So far, I can see that gcd($n$,$n+1$)$=1$ and $m \equiv_4 1$ and $m=a^2 + b^2$ for some integers a,b. I'm guessing I need to reach a contradiction.

At this point, I am stuck. Any hints?

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that is a good observation. I updated title. Another poster commented and deleted an approach using quadratic formula. I think he made a mistake in his c algebra but this leads to showing $2m^3 + 1$ must be a square if there is a solution. That's another angle.

Comment: There was another mistake in the deleted answer in that the denominator should be $4$, not $2$.  That makes the whole thing not work.  It might be possible to rescue.

Comment: Why do I get the vibe that André Nicolas posted a nice answer to this years ago? In other words, this is probably a duplicate. Can't find it now :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equation is equivalent to $(2(2n+1))^2+4=(2m)^3$.

$a^2+4=b^3$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ is a Mordell's Equation. See [this paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf) (page $6$) for an elementary solution that uses $\Bbb Z[i]$ (the [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer)). The only solutions are $(a,b)=(\pm 2,2), (\pm 11, 5)$.

$2m$ is even, so $2m=2$ and $2(2n+1)=\pm 2$, so the only integer solutions are $(m,n)=(1,-1),(1,0)$.

Comment: Very nicely done. Thank you. Unless there is a simpler approach, this may be another exercise that Burton made harder than intended - imaginary numbers used in your linked paper are not even introduced in this textbook.  I am using a very early edition since I found a cheap hardcopy. At any rate, I learned about Mordell equations.

Comment: @topoquestion Where exactly did you find this problem?

Comment: Elementary Number Theory Revised Printing. Copyright 1980, 1976. So 2nd edition perhaps. By David M. Burton. This is exercise 17 in section 12.2 I don't know, can I unaccept an answer?

Comment: @topoquestion You've just unaccepted it.