# Sums of squares (Proof)

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

Prove that $n^2 + (n + 1)^2 = m^3$ does not have solutions in the positive integers.

I guess that the proof is by contradiction, but if I suppose it, I can't find the contradiction.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I made minimal progress that maybe someone else will better know how to work with (if it's useful at all). $m$ must be an odd number satisfying $n < \frac{m^3}{2} < n + 1$

Comment: @infinitylord How did you prove that? If $n<\frac{m^3}2<n+1$, I might be able to prove that only $n=0$ and $n=-1$ are solutions and answer the question.

Comment: If that's the case then you've proven it. If $m$ satisfies that inequality, then since $m^3$ would be odd, $m^3/2$ would be equal to $b+ \frac{1}{2}$ for some integer $b$. The inequality then gives $b=n$, so $m^3= 2n+1$. But then $2n^2=0$, so $n=0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was mistaken. I forgot to divide the middle inequality by $n+1$. The bound is then $n(n+1) < \frac{m^3}{2} < (n+1)^2$ which sadly is not nearly as nice.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672211/n2-n12-m3-has-no-solution-in-the-positive-integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Currently Incomplete Answer**

I am leaving it up for now to see if it helps anyone and so that if I think of something, I can edit it into the answer.

$$\begin{align}
2n^2+2n+1=m^3&\implies2n^2+2n=m^3-1\\
&\implies2n(n+1)=(m-1)(m^2+m+1)\\
&\implies m\equiv1\bmod4\\
&\implies2n(n+1)=4k((4k+1)^2+(4k+1)+1)\\
&\implies n(n+1)=32k^3+24k^2+6k\\
\end{align}$$
For this to use only integers, $n=2ak$ or $2ak-1$. Substituting into the equation yields
$$2a^2k\pm a=a(2ak\pm1)=16k^2+12k+3$$

Comment: I apologize, I biffed the algebra in my derivation. See my comment.

Comment: @infinitylord Actually, so did I. Apparently, $m\equiv1\bmod4\nrightarrow m^3\equiv1\bmod64$.